# Springer format full width text

Tags: margins

I'd like to use the Springer format [`llncls.cls`](http://www.springer.com/computer/lncs?SGWID=0-164-6-793341-0) but with full width text. Which settings do I need to change in order to remove the wide page margin?

Comment: Is there a special reason why you want to use this "not-well-supported" document class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `geometry`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{kantlipsum} % just for the example

\begin{document}

\kant

\end{document}
```

Check the documentation of `geometry` for more options, this `margin=2cm` is just to show that it works.

[image]